# Build does not create any artifacts

Tags: azure, azure-devops

So I'm trying to create a build containing all of my testing assemblies, so I can run my release pipeline and all of my test in it. The build however is not creating any artifacs and my pipeline, therefore, has no binaries to run the tests. What am I doing wrong?

Pictures of my build setup:
[image: The build process]

[image: The copy process]

[image: The artifact publish process]

```
YAML for the build can be found here: https://pastebin.com/qumhiVKZ
```

Comment: Can you check the logs if something copied to artifacts folder on not?

Comment: Could you please share the YAML for the build definition? That way we can see the big picture.

Comment: You can find my YAML for the build here: https://pastebin.com/qumhiVKZ

Comment: I have looked at the logs... It seems like the "Publish artifacts" is looking in d:/a/1/a instead of d:/a/1/s, where the build is putting the files... Why does it do this?

Comment: I have still not found a solution.. Maybe it's some small config change+

Answer (score 0):

The build task produces a publishable MSDeploy package to `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\`, this is because of the `/p:PackageAsSingleFile=true` parameter. I believe what is actually published is the MSDeploy package that contains a `.zip` file (the actual package), and a couple of batch scripts and a `.xml` parameter file to deploy it.

Removing the following parameters:

```
/p:PackageAsSingleFile=true
/p:packageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"
```

.. and using the following parameters instead might help:

```
 /p:DeployOnBuild=true
 /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish
 /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem
 /p:DeleteExistingFiles=True
 /p:publishUrl="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)"
```

It's hard to tell the exact set of parameters you should use without access to the full YAML definition of the build task.

Comment: Ty for your answer Mehmet! You can see my entire YAML of the build here: https://pastebin.com/qumhiVKZ ... I will give the parameters a look :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the error you meet should is **found 0 files** in your Copy File task.

[image]

The error caused by your **Contents** of Copy File task is incorrect. You should modify it as :

```
**\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\**
```

In fact, you can know the file is be copied through checking the **drop** file of **Build Summary**.

If file exists and copied, there will some files showed under the drop{buildname}\bin\Release.

[image]